# I want to override customer-account-index.xml from magento-customer

Tags: magento2, module, layout, custom

If we want to override `customer-account-index.xml` from `magento-customer.` Where I should override?

By making folder name as `Magento_Customer` in `app\design\vendor\theme or app\code\vendor\module..`

basically i want to section below account information in my account page of customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make folder Magento_Customer inside  app\design\vendor\theme and this will override as a theme.

Comment: So then I can add block within same folder and template as well.

Comment: Yes you should also add your own custom template too.

Comment: How should I give path to block in customer_account_index.xml?